# Regex to identify 3+ consecutive of same alpha/numeric

Tags: regex, posix

I have been trying to write/find a regex that will identify where there are 3+ consecutive instances of an alpha/numeric.

Example:

```
CHAIRMAN AAAAAAAND CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER
```

this would be a match b/c of the `'**AAAAAAA**'`

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried several different things.  Here is the last one I tried ...

(?i)(?:([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,})*

Comment: [`(([A-Za-z\d])\2{2,})`](https://regex101.com/r/wMMWJH/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with backreferences: `.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1\1.*`

Here, each `\1` matches the character matched in the capturing group.

Experiment with it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/a7cSHd/1).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, here is an example in Python:

```
import re

text = "CHAIRMAN AAAAAAAND CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER"

regex = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9])\\1\\1")

if re.search(regex, text):
    print ("yuppers")
```

The regex itself is looking for any letter or number, followed by whatever letter or number it matched twice.  You can do stuff like:

```
[A-Z\d]\\1{2}
```

and make the call of the regex case insensitive instead but with little regexes like this I think just spelling it out is easier to read for others down the road.

Answer (score 0):

the

```
echo 'CHAIRMAN AAAAAAAND CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER' | grep -E -o '([A-Z])\1{2,}'
```

outputs:

```
AAAAAAA
```

`grep` tool for Unix and Linux
`-E`  PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
`-o`  show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
 `([A-Z])` matches a single character and takes care of the match as a back-reference
`\1{2,}` using that back-reference plus 2 or more that is equal **3 consecutive character or more**

So:

```
echo 'not nn nnn oo ooo tt ttt 123 11 111' | grep -E -o '(\w)\1{2,}'
```

will match:

```
nnn
ooo
ttt
111
```

Or:

```
echo 'not nnn ooo ttt 123 111' | grep -E -o '([[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]])\1{2,}'
```

has the same output.

But as may or may not you know `\w` match the `_` as well therefore using character class like `[a-z]` or build-in character class like `[[:alpha:]]` is a better choice.